# Android how to set transparency to custom part of ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I would like to set a custom part of an image view to be transparent. However, the partial view inside  does not have to be a rectangle. It could be parallelogram, triangle, etc... I know I can retrieve the corners of the shape that I want to set to transparent, I just don't know what to do with those inputs.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to manually manipulate a bitmap that you set to the image view.

```
Bitmap someBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.someimage);
bmp.setPixel(x,y,Color.TRANSPARENT);
someImageView.setBitmap(someBitmap);
```

*Code not tested.*

Comment: Thanks this was useful, but if I want to set the partial image inside, I would have to check all x,y values to the boundaries and set those specifically and this becomes expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`